# Ping-Pong Suggested Edits and Related Approval & Rollback Confusion

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-question

I am a bit perplexed and disturbed by the results of a couple suggested edits I reviewed for a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25074820/1810429) - specifically what are now [revisions 6 and 7](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25074820/revisions).

### Revision 6: Adding [mysql]

When I saw the addition of [mysql] to the question's tags as a suggested edit, I rejected it.  The question clearly has nothing to do with MySQL.  Done - or so I thought.  (**EDIT:** Revisiting the suggested edit's details reminded me that a single peer review does not determine the outcome of the suggested edit.  Okay, moving on....)

### Revision 7: Removing [mysql] - Approval & Rollback Confusion

When I then saw the removal of [mysql] from the question's tags as a suggested edit a minute later, I paused to look at the question's edit history before rejecting it - mostly:

1. *marveling at how the addition of [mysql] to the question's tags was ostensibly approved*
2. wanting to double check what exactly was going on

As I suspected, the same user who suggested the addition of [mysql] also suggested the removal of [mysql] next-to-immediately; but what amazed me more was to see that the removal of [mysql] had been approved by the time I browsed to the question's edit history.  (Another 2 points for the user in question of course.)  *The addition of [mysql] was invalid to start.  Isn't this what rollbacks (to revision 5 in this case) are for?*

Never assume malice where incompetence will do (or whatever Heinlein said via Lazarus Long to that effect), but this felt like a possible case of gaming edits for points.

### Further Rollback Confusion

This bothered me enough that I quickly tried to roll the question back to revision 5 - i.e. before [mysql] was added...and then removed.  No dice.  I clicked the confirmation message box to indicate I was sure that I wanted to roll back; but the rollback didn't take.  I experimented with rolling back to revision 6 instead and found that the rollback stuck...but that I still could not roll back to revision 5 subsequently.

Uggghhh....  I am probably missing something regarding rollbacks - since I have rolled back just once before; but this was disheartening.

### Bottom-Line

Can anyone shed authoritative light on whether I am perceiving all this accurately, what I may be missing with respect to any of what I have explained?

Comment: Could be an innocent mistake from the user who suggested the MySQL tag, and then he just tried to undo it?

Comment: @CoderDojo: Right - Heinlein's point. :)  I was just amazed at how it played out.